# What is $\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{\log x} \frac{1}{\sin t} dt$?

Tags: integration, analysis

How can one calculate

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{\log x} \frac{1}{\sin t} dt$$

Comment: What is the base of the $\log$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother with analysing and manipulating the integrand. Nothing at all happens to it in this exercise. This is the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

You have a function
$$
f(x) = \int_1^x\frac1{\sin t}\,dt
$$
and you are asked about the derivative of $f(\log x)$. The chain rule (assuming your logarithm is the natural logarithm) gives
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(\log x) = \frac 1xf'(\log x)
$$
and the FTC gives
$$
f'(x) = \frac1{\sin x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By Chain Rule it is $\frac 1 {\sin (\log x)} \frac 1 x$ if the logarithm is to base $e$.

Answer (score 1):

With $y:=\exp t$ the integral is $\int_e^x\frac{dy}{y\sin\ln y}$, with $x$-derivative $\frac{1}{x\sin\ln x}$.